# BASH - Timed Input - Show countdown

Tags: bash, input

I have a bash script that asks the user for their details.

I'm setting a limit to how long we wait for the input. I've found this and it appears to what I want.

```
timelimit=5
echo -e " You have $timelimit seconds\n Enter your name quickly: \c"
name=""
read -t $timelimit name
#read -t $timelimit name <&1 
# for bash versions bellow 3.x
if [ ! -z "$name" ]
then
echo -e "\n Your name is $name"
else
echo -e "\n TIME OUT\n You failed to enter your name"
fi
```

It shows "You have 5 seconds..." any way to update the output so it shows 4,3,2,1 etc as it counts down ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work and shouldn't overwrite input, bit more long winded than the other solutions.

```
#!/bin/bash

abend() 
{       
        stty sane
        exit
        #Resets stty and then exits script
}

DoAction(){

        stty -echo 
        #Turn off echo
        tput sc
        #Save cursor position
        echo -ne "\033[0K\r"
        # Remove previous line
        tput cuu1
        #Go to previous line
        tput el
        #clear to end of line
        echo "You have $(($time-$count)) seconds"
        #Echo timer
        echo -n "$Keys"
        #Echo currently typed text
        stty echo
        #turn echo on
        tput rc
        #return cursor
}


main()
{
trap abend SIGINT # Trap ctrl-c to return terminal to normal
stty -icanon time 0 min 0 -echo
#turn of echo and set read time to nothing
keypress=''

time=5
echo "You have $time seconds"
while Keys=$Keys$keypress; do
        sleep 0.05
        read keypress && break
        ((clock  = clock + 1 ))
        if [[ clock -eq 20 ]];then
                ((count++))
                clock=0
                DoAction $Keys
        fi
        [[ $count -eq $time ]] && echo "you have run out of time" && abend



done

stty sane
echo Your username was $Keys
echo "Thanks for using this script."
exit 0
}

main
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but there is a delay when entering the name. any ideas ?

Comment: This is nearly perfect ;) Only main issue I have is if the timeout is 10 seconds or more. Then the wording changes to show: `You have 9 secondss`  You get an extra s on the end.

Comment: Thanks I'll try your change. I've just come up with : `  timer=$(printf %02d $(($time-$count)))
        echo -e "You have $timer seconds"` Which seems to work !

Comment: One quick comment.  Can you enable backspace / delete when using read ? I tried -e but that failed. Anyway to do it ?

Comment: @Rocket I don't think you can, but i will have a look

Comment: Thanks - I've found a few posts talking about setting `stty erase ^?` but I can't seem to get that to work..

Answer (score 5):

I have tried most of these answers and none of them worked perfectly for me.
Been playing with this for a local developer deployment script.
This solves a few of the issues noted, like including printed output, etc.
Also wrapped as a function for portability. I'm keen to see any improvements.

Here is my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
# set -euo pipefail

function read_yn {
  MESSAGE=$1
  TIMEOUTREPLY=$2
  READTIMEOUT=$3
  NORMALREPLY="Y"
  if [ -z "${TIMEOUTREPLY}" ]; then
      TIMEOUTREPLY="Y"
  fi
  if [ -z "${READTIMEOUT}" ]; then
      READTIMEOUT=5
  fi
  TIMEOUTREPLY_UC=$( echo $TIMEOUTREPLY | awk '{print toupper($0)}' )
  TIMEOUTREPLY_LC=$( echo $TIMEOUTREPLY | awk '{print tolower($0)}' )
  if [ "${TIMEOUTREPLY_UC}" == "Y" ]; then
    NORMALREPLY="N"
  fi
  NORMALREPLY_UC=$( echo $NORMALREPLY | awk '{print toupper($0)}' )
  NORMALREPLY_LC=$( echo $NORMALREPLY | awk '{print tolower($0)}' )
  for (( i=$READTIMEOUT; i>=1; i--)); do
    printf "\r${MESSAGE} [${NORMALREPLY_UC}${NORMALREPLY_LC}/${TIMEOUTREPLY_UC}${TIMEOUTREPLY_LC}] ('${TIMEOUTREPLY_UC}' in ${i}s) "
    read -s -n 1 -t 1 WAITREADYN
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      if [[ "${WAITREADYN}" = "y" || "${WAITREADYN}" = "Y" || "${WAITREADYN}" = "n" || "${WAITREADYN}" = "N" ]]; then
        break
      else
        sleep 1
      fi
    fi
  done
  printf "\r${MESSAGE} [${NORMALREPLY_UC}${NORMALREPLY_LC}/${TIMEOUTREPLY_UC}${TIMEOUTREPLY_LC}] ('${TIMEOUTREPLY_UC}' in 0s)      "
  yn=""
  if [ -z $WAITREADYN ]; then
    echo -e "\nNo input entered: Defaulting to '${TIMEOUTREPLY_UC}'"
    yn="${TIMEOUTREPLY_UC}"
  else
    echo -e "\n${WAITREADYN}"
    yn="${WAITREADYN}"
  fi
}

read_yn "TESTING" "y" 5
```

**GIST:** https://gist.github.com/djravine/7a66478c37974940e8c39764d59d35fa

**LIVE DEMO:** https://replit.com/@DJRavine/read-input-with-visible-countdownsh?v=1

Comment: One note, this doesn't handle unexpected input. In your example (even the live demo), I could press any other key on the keyboard and it would happily report that as the pressed key. This might work as a generic "read_key" function, but for a function called "read_yn" I was kinda expecting that it would only accept `Y` or `N` as input and silently reject other input (and continue counting down).

Comment: @DoktorJ I have improoved my solution with your input. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: this doesn't consume the extra keys that are pressed and they end up on the CLI

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
$ cat test.sh 
total=5  # total wait time in seconds
count=0  # counter
while [ ${count} -lt ${total} ] ; do
    tlimit=$(( $total - $count ))
    echo -e "\rYou have ${tlimit} seconds to enter your name: \c"
    read -t 1 name
    test ! -z "$name" && { break ; }
    count=$((count+1))
done
if [ ! -z "$name" ] ; then
    echo -e "\nyour name is $name"
else
    echo -e "\ntime out"
fi
```

Comment: Wont that overwrite what you are typing though ?

Comment: @123 the result would still be correct (stdin is line-buffered), however yes: on the terminal you'll see strange things

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Any idea why only numbers mess up on my answer. The end result is correct but it seems to have a nightmare saving the numbers in the correct order when echoing in `Doaction` and takes about 2 seconds to sort itself out.

Comment: This seems to work, but if you pause the cursor moves to the beginning of the input ! any idea why ?

Comment: @123 yes, you're right. rewriting the whole line will overwrite what your typing... thinking...

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

timelimit=6
name=""

for (( i = 1 ; i <= $timelimit; i++ )); do
        echo -ne "\rYou have $(expr $timelimit - $i) seconds. Enter your name quickly: \c"
        [ ! -z "$name" ] && { break ; }
        read -t 1 name
done

if [ -z "$name" ]; then
        echo -e "\n TIME OUT\n You failed to enter your name"
else
        echo -e "\n Your name is $name"
fi
```

this should work

Comment: This seems to work, but if you pause the cursor moves to the beginning of the input ! any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine and fast for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Sets starttimestamp
starttime=$(date +%s)
#Sets timeout
timeout=5
#sets successflag default to false
success=false

#Save Cursorposition
echo -n -e "\033[s"

#While time not up
while [ $(($starttime+$timeout)) -gt $(date +%s) ] ; do
        #Return to saved Cursorpositon
        echo -n -e "\033[u"
        #Display time left
        echo "$(((starttime+timeout)-$(date +%s))) seconds left"
        #Ask for 1 char then go on in loop make it look like an ongoing input by adding the user variable to the prompt
        if read -p foo="Username: $user" -n 1 -t 1 c ; then
                #If user hits return in time c will be empty then break out of loop and set success true
                if [[ $c == "" ]] ; then
                        success=true
                        break
                fi
                # Append latest character to user variable
                user=${user}${c}
                unset c
        fi
done

if $success ; then
        echo "Yiha!"
else
        echo "Too late!"
fi
```